# Pandas - duplicate row on condition and increase only one value in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe (subset constructed as below):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Id': [12345678, 23456789, 34567890, 45678901, 56789012],
                           'score': [0.0123, 0.0145, 0.0345, 0.5660, 1.0000],
                           'target': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]})
```

```
    Id          score    target
0   12345678    0.0123      0
1   23456789    0.0145      0
2   34567890    0.0345      0
3   45678901    0.5660      1
4   56789012    1.0000      1
```

I want to add one row between each row if the **score** difference is 0.01 or larger. The score for the new row should then be the mean of the two compared rows and the **ID** and **target** should stay the same as the first row. The desired output is:

```
    Id          score    target
0   12345678    0.0123      0
1   23456789    0.0145      0
2   23456789    0.0245      0
3   34567890    0.0345      0
4   34567890    0.30025     0
5   45678901    0.5660      1
6   45678901    0.7830      1
7   56789012    1.0000      1
```

I only know how to replicate/duplicate specific rows but not sure how to do this with condition and if to somehow use apply or not.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `rolling`+`mean` to get the average of pairs of rows.

Then select the rows to keep from the initial difference between the scores.

Finally, concatenate the two dataframes and reorder.

```
(pd.concat([df1,
            (df1.assign(score=df1['score'].rolling(2).mean().shift(-1))
                .loc[df1['score'].diff(-1).abs().gt(0.01)]
             )]
          )
   .sort_index()
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

output:

```
         Id    score  target
0  12345678  0.01230       0
1  23456789  0.01450       0
2  23456789  0.02450       0
3  34567890  0.03450       0
4  34567890  0.30025       0
5  45678901  0.56600       1
6  45678901  0.78300       1
7  56789012  1.00000       1
```